# Why is my ceiling light permanently dim?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I'm trying to figure out the wiring situation here for a surface-mounted ceiling LED light.

There are 2 black wires, 1 white and a ground. As it currently stands the light won't turn on or off, it's a dim light. The dim light goes away if I take the single black wire out. Or is there a second white wire maybe hidden behind the box needed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's a very strange wiring arrangement. Are there no other conductors in the near cable? Where are the ground wires? Where on the planet is this?

Comment: To answer your final question, no wires should be "hidden" or terminate outside the box. I would pull the clamps off both ports and see what you see.

Comment: Two of the ground wires are visible (with some paint on them) if you zoom in. The fixture is hanging by its ground wire, so it's the straight one, and yellow-striped green on zooming. The white and ground from the cable closer to us (left side) are unaccounted for / invisible in this picture, however.

Comment: It's on a single switch btw (no dimmer)

Comment: Can you take a picture of the box from the opposite angle?  I want to see if the single black wire is in a cable with a chopped-off neutral, or if it's a single.  Doesn't look like THHN/THWN to me.

Comment: @ChrisO - Added a new photo. It seems its connected to one of the wall outlets as I had a light plugged into the outlet to check and a slight pull of the single black wire turns the light in the wall outlet off.

Answer (score 4):

***Harper's Law of Seemingly Unrelated Problems*** says that if you are chasing a problem A which is vexing, and in the course of that see a *seemingly* unrelated problem B, **correct problem B**.  Either problem A will magically self-fix, or the path to fixing A will become much more apparent.

You have a NEC 300.3 violation and a fire or shock hazard owing to the black wire on the left not being associated with any white wire.  That needs to be investigated and resolved.

Doing so will expose what is needed to fix the light problem.

How was the wiring arranged when you found it?

Comment: $5 says the singleton black wire is the un-switched hot, and the black-white /2 cable we see goes to a switch (switch loop). Without being connected to actual supply neutral (and un-switched), the LED light is coming on faintly due to capacitance.